# Compare function failing when null value passed to one of the parameters

Tags: javascript, sahi

i am using the below code for comparing two values:

```
function CompareValue($ValueTobePresent,$ExpectedValue)
{
    var $ValueTobePresent=$ValueTobePresent.toLocaleLowerCase();
    var $ExpectedValue = $ExpectedValue.toLocaleLowerCase();
    _assertEqual($ValueTobePresent, $ExpectedValue);

}
```

Now my problem is if a null value is passed the function fails with the below message:
Logging exception: Cannot call method "toLocaleLowerCase" of null [81 ms]
Cannot call method "toLocaleLowerCase" of null.

Is there a way i can solve it out so that i can handle the null values also?
Also i have around 25 comparisons to do so i want the code not to be very time consuming.

Thanks

Comment: `$ValueTobePresent = ($ValueTobePresent == null) ? $ValueTobePresent : ""` I think it'll also handle the `undefined` condition.

Comment: Are you comparing any type of values or just strings? Is it possible to pass Arrays, Objects, Date objects, numbers, booleans as $ValueTobePresent and $ExpectedValue parameters?

Comment: Mostly i am comparing only strings. It is just that i take values from two applications and i compare it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `var` inside the `function`
2. Use [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to check if arguments passed are valid
3. Use `toString()` before calling `toLocaleLowerCase()`

Code:

```
function CompareValue($ValueTobePresent, $ExpectedValue) {
    $ValueTobePresent = $ValueTobePresent ? $ValueTobePresent.toString().toLocaleLowerCase() : '';
    $ExpectedValue = $ExpectedValue ? $ExpectedValue.toString().toLocaleLowerCase() : '';
    _assertEqual($ValueTobePresent, $ExpectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tushar Thanks. i used your code and its resolved without much performance issues

Answer (score 1):

You could replace null values with empty strings if this works for you

```
function CompareValue($ValueTobePresent,$ExpectedValue)
{
    var $ValueTobePresent = ($ValueTobePresent || '').toLocaleLowerCase();
    var $ExpectedValue = ($ExpectedValue || '').toLocaleLowerCase();
    _assertEqual($ValueTobePresent, $ExpectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Try `CompareValue(1, 1)` or `CompareValue(true, false)`

Comment: The initial snippet does not support such calls. Also using toString() would produce results like 
CompareValue('null', null)
CompareValue('1', 1)

It really depends what OP wants, but my assumption is that we are comparing strings.

Comment: `but my assumption is that we are comparing strings.` If this is the case, this question would not be present here